# iOS: Can't get first item value from Range<CGFloat>

Tags: ios, swift, range, cgfloat

I have a Range with float numbers. I need to get the first and the last elements of the range. With Range everything works fine. However when I try to get values from float range I get error "Ambiguous reference to member 'first'". How do I get values from float range?

I tried casting, unwrapping - same error. Looked at posts with similar problem but nothing seems to work.

let range: Range = 1.0..<3.22

let first: CGFloat = range.first     (!)(Ambiguous reference to member 'first')

I expect to get the first item from the range, instead I get an error.

Comment: Range is not an array, there is nothing like first, try to use `lowerBound`

Comment: wow I feel stupid. It works! Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`first` is a method of the `Collection` protocol (and `last` a method of `BidirectionalCollection`). A [`Range`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/range) is a (bidirectional) collection only if the underlying element type is an integer type, or any other type that conforms to the `Strideable` protocol with an integer stride. Example:

```
let intRange = 1..<10
print(intRange.first!) // 1
print(intRange.last!)  // 9
```

A range of floating point numbers is not a collection, so there is no `first` or `last` method. But you can retrieve the lower/upper *bound:*

```
let range: Range<CGFloat> = 1.0..<3.22
print(range.lowerBound)  // 1.0
print(range.upperBound)  // 3.22
```

Comment: Worth to note that no floating point type ranges can be `Collection`s, because to do so you need to be able to sequence numbers between lower and upper bound. You can't do this with floating point numbers at all. You can't have `next` number for any `CGFloat`, and you can't tell which number in the range would be `nth`.

Comment: @user28434: In fact you could: The binary floating point types can only represent finitely many values, and actually there are  `nextUp`/`nextDown` methods. But it would be of no practical usage.